# Excel formula to calculate intersected dates?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I searched through internet and came up with nothing. I have two tables. one includes work dates and the other has vacation dates. I have to find the intersected dates.

Let me give an example;

**Work Table**

```
1|  A    |      B             |       C          |          D
2|Person |    Work Start Date | work finish Date |Intersected Vacations
3|Mike   |         01.08.2013 |       10.08.2013 |1  (Needed to find)
4|John   |         16.08.2013 |       25.10.2013 |3  (Needed to find)
```

**Vacations Table**

```
1|A      |B                   |C
2|Person |Vacation Start Date |Vacation End Date
3|Mike   |         05.08.2013 |       05.08.2013
4|John   |         20.09.2013 |       21.09.2013
5|John   |         01.10.2013 |       01.10.2013
```

So, I need an excel formula to calculate the vacations between the work days.

Comment: You can simply add & subtract date values... you can also use other maths operators like `>` and `<`, etc. This is probably a simple application of some `VLOOKUP` type formula., i.e., lookup "Mike" in the Work Table, and then test to see whether the vacation date falls within the work dates, etc.

Comment: In your example one of the vacation periods ends on a Saturday. Do the days of the week matter, e.g. if a vacation period crosses a weekend do the weekend days get included or not?

Comment: when applied your solution to my real data, I came across with that problem. if there is a weekend in any vacation period, how can formula return only the workdays? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are counting all days within the periods, including Saturdays and Sundays you can use this "array formula" as per my screenshot below:

Formula is as follows in D3:

`=SUM(IF(A$8:A$10=A3,IF(C$8:C$10>=B3,IF(B$8:B$10<=C3,IF(C$8:C$10>C3,C3,C$8:C$10)-IF(B$8:B$10<B3,B3,B$8:B$10)+1))))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copied down to D4

This may look like overkill for your small example but I'm assuming your real data is larger - this solution can be extended as required, even for multiple unsorted vacation periods

[image]